# Macro to merge data on to template

Tags: vba, macros, mail-merge

I am attempting to basically do a mail merge in Excel. I would like to take employee data from one Excel worksheet and populate fields on an Wxcel template.

So far I have written code to open the template form but am having difficutlites populating the employee number into one of the fields.  The remaining fields are formulas tied to that employee number.  I would like to do this for all 400+ records I have and save them as PDF's.

Comment: Welcome to SU! We're not a script writing service, but we can help.  :) Please edit your question to explain where exactly you're getting stuck, what you've attempted already and the results.

Comment: I used this site and was able to find a member who wrote code that would open a template and populate certain fields using employee information.  They were then able to save each template by employee as a separate form.  I am having trouble getting the employee number to populate in the correct cell on my template from my original dataset.  I would also like to be able to save each one by employee and do this on a loop so I do not have to hard code each employee number into my template.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion, assuming you have Word:

Create a LIST in Excel that has all the data about ONE employee on ONE ROW.
Then use that Excel sheet as the ODBC source for a plain Mailmerge in Word.

Comment: I can do that no problem.  The issue is the template they want me to use is in Excel.  Also, when I do the mail merge into Word, it is not formatted the way it needs to be.